# Confused by Cubit Bloc, was working fine but now not

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I had my theme being changed successfully a few weeks ago, however since updating flutter it no longer works.

The BlocProvider no longer works, nor my Cubit. I just cannot understand what has changed.

I am receiving the error on my cubit as follows.....

**'ThemeCubit' doesn't extend 'Bloc<Object, Object>'.
Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'Bloc<Object, Object>'.**

My theme cubit..

```
class ThemeCubit extends Cubit<ThemeState> {
  ThemeCubit() : super(ThemeStateInitial(themeData: appThemeData.values.first));

  bool themeChanged = false;

  void changeTheme() {
    themeChanged = !themeChanged;
    final newTheme = themeChanged == false
        ? appThemeData.values.first
        : appThemeData.values.last;
    emit(ThemeStateChanged(themeData: newTheme));
  }
}
```

My theme state

```
abstract class ThemeState {
  const ThemeState();
}

class ThemeStateInitial extends ThemeState {
  final ThemeData themeData;
  const ThemeStateInitial({this.themeData});

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object o) {
    if (identical(this, o)) return true;

    return o is ThemeStateInitial && o.themeData == themeData;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => themeData.hashCode;
}

class ThemeStateChanged extends ThemeState {
  final ThemeData themeData;
  const ThemeStateChanged({this.themeData});

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object o) {
    if (identical(this, o)) return true;

    return o is ThemeStateChanged && o.themeData == themeData;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => themeData.hashCode;
}
```

My UI

```
class AppWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => ThemeCubit(),
      child: BlocBuilder<ThemeCubit, ThemeState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
              systemNavigationBarColor: state.themeData == ThemeData.dark() ? Colors.black : Colors.white, // navigation bar color
              statusBarColor: state.themeData == ThemeData.dark() ? Colors.white : Colors.black, // status bar color
            ));
            return MaterialApp(
              title: 'Material App',
              theme: state.themeData ??= appThemeData.values.first, 
              home: const Scaffold(
                appBar: PreferredSize(
                  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(65.0),
                  child: AppBar(mainMenuDisplayed: false),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

My button...

```
class TrialButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider.value(
      value: BlocProvider.of<ThemeCubit>(context),
      child: Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 50,
        child: RaisedButton(
          textColor: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {
            debugPrint("button pressed");
            final themeCubit = context.bloc<ThemeCubit>();
            themeCubit.changeTheme();
          },
          child: Text('PRESS', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As I say this was working fine last week, but unfortunately has stopped working and I am unsure why.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you resolved it? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Sorry, just seen this. I ended up just not using Cubit, as it's been incorporated into Bloc now. The Cubit stand alone package has been "discontinued", unfortunately I didn't realise that until visiting the cubit pub dev page